# HTC ONE X Custom ROM Issue

Tags: operating-systems, android, rom

I tried to install a custom ROM on my htc one X without making any backup. My new custom ROM did not installed correctly. It is just showing X type logo of custom ROM after htc splash screen. I can go to hboot, fastboot and recovery menus. I can also access the memory card. My problem is that I do not know how can I add new custom ROM on memory card so I can install it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are able to boot into `fastboot` mode, you can use this to flash your ROM. Details can be found at our sister-site, take a look e.g. at [I can FastBoot my device. How can I reinstall an Android image to it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35174/16575).

However, this requires to have compatible images, as `fastboot` flashes single partitions (and not full ROMs, at least to my knowledge). If you don't have such, and don't know how to convert your ROM into this format, on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) you can find another useful ressource: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) This might help you finding a compatible ROM. A question like "How can I make my ROM image compatible with fastboot?", including the facts from your above question, would be on-topic there as well, just in case.

For more information on `fastboot`, you can refer to the [fastboot tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) at the mentioned sister-site.